# Programming for non-javascript users

Tags: javascript, jquery

To ensure that my site is friendly to non-javascript users, I've built it without using JavaScript, and added it once the site was built.

So now I have a link as following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/panel" id="showPanel">Expand</a>
```

But if JavaScript is enabled, I use the following code:

```
$("#showPanel").attr("href", "#showPanel");
```

to make the link point to #showPanel instead of http://example.com/panel

While this all works fine, I can't help but wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: What are your concerns with this approach?

Comment: Well, for a page with a lot of links, it's very tedious indeed. But also, I have no idea if this will effect the page load speed significantly.

Comment: If the JavaScript runs once the page has already loaded then there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Make sure to load your JS files from the END of the body tag so that the page can render before it bothers downloading the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load JS files at the bottom of the page. If the JavaScript you are running is once the page has already loaded, then there shouldn't be an issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // change links.
});
```

If you are trying to reduce the raw number of lines of JS, you could try to follow some convention and automate the changing of the URLs:

```
var changeAllLinks = function () {
    var allLinks = $("a[href^='http://example.com']");
    for (int i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].attr("href", "#show" + /* substring for the path */);
    }
};
```

Just an idea, as something like that (conceptually) may work. You could follow a convention where all links without JS are in the form `<a href="http://example.com/foo">` and the change them with JS to `<a href="#showFoo">`. That way you could loop through all the links and substring to get the path, capitalize the first letter, prepend a `#show` to the front, and pop it into the `href` attribute like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that this method is very tedious. This would by my major concern. You might want to find a way to automate this. I've come up with this solution using the rel-attribute as a selector.

```
<a href="showThing1" rel="javascriptable">This links via javascript</a>
<a href="showThing2">Always links to a new page</a>
```

```
// load when ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find all links with the correct rel attribute
    $('a[rel="javascriptable"]').each(function(index) {
        // Change the href attribute
        oldlink = $(this).attr('href');
        newlink = # + oldlink;
        $(this).attr('href', newlink);
    });
});
```

My jquery is a bit rusty so i guess copy/pasting doesn't really work

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about page load times.
That's only a measure of how long it takes for things to stop downloading, not a measure of how long it takes for a person to be able to use the site.

When it *is* a concern is when pageload blocks the ability to use a page (or view a page) -- like if you load all of your JS at the top of a page, prior to loading CSS, for instance.

Personally, I think that your format is fine-ish, but that looks like you're doing a lot of `id`-assignment, and jQuery listening ***by-hand***, which is a horrible, awful thing.

Why not do something like use html5 `data-set` attributes?

```
<a data-linkType="JS-Override" data-methodName="doSomethingInternally">link</a>
```

From your program, you can then call the `dataset` of the element.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
[].forEach.call(anchors, function(anchor) {
    if (anchor.dataset.linkType !== "JS-Override") { return; }

    var extension = anchor.dataset.methodName;
    anchor.addEventListener("...", function () { setHash(extension); }, false); 
});
```

It's a very trivial example, but it works.
Support for dataset is good, currently. To get it to work across all browsers including old-IE, it needs to be wrapped in a simple API (new browsers read from dataset, old browsers need to read through their attribute lists for "data-XXX" attributes -- jQuery wraps this into `.data();`

And of course, you might have a lot of anchors on your page, and only a handful of them are going to do the thing that you're looking for right now...  ...so the trick there would be to grab them by a class that you give them, so that you aren't sorting by every `a` on the page.

...or, alternatively, if you know that each `a` which is a special internal page, is contained within a menu div, or a settings div or whatever, then just grab those ones:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu"),
    jsLinks = menu.getElementsByTagName("a");

[].forEach.call(jsLinks, function (anchor) { /* everything mentioned before */ });
```